Enforce type argument of a decorator to be a subset of the method return type
I'm trying to enforce the type argument of a decorator to be a subset of the decorated methods return type but I'm not able to solve this:
function foo<U>() {
    return function<T extends U>(target: any, propertyKey: any, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<() => T>){};
}

class Bar { 
    baz: number = 0;
}

class Baz {
    @foo<Bar>()        // should be valid but it fails with 1241
    @foo<null>()       // should be valid but it fails with 1241
    @foo<Bar | null>() // should be valid and it is valid
    @foo<number>()     // should fail and it does fail
    qux(): Bar | null {
        return new Bar();
    }
}

I don't want to change the return type, and I guess this is my problem here. I just want to have a check for U being a subset of T.
EDIT: I'm using experimentalDecorators, see https://tsplay.dev/w28pYm.

None of those are valid. Are you using ES decorators (which is now the default type of decorator and is going to be the standard going forward) or TS experimental decorators? If it's TS experimental decorators you should [edit] to say that and to give the compiler options you use.

(see prev comment). It looks like you have extends backwards. You want U extends T, not the other way around. TS doesn't have lower bound constraints, so you can't say T super U directly. You can emulate that constraint, as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? (And note that you need some structure in Bar, otherwise number is assignable to Bar). If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz My bad it was a typo, I'll fix the post and thanks for the solution!

That's not a typo, TS doesn't let you write U extends T in that location. I didn't mean "you mistyped it", I meant "you got your logic wrong".  Now you get even more errors. Do me a favor and undo your edit because it makes things worse, not better.  Then read the initial comment about which decorators you're using, and [edit] to address that.  And then I can suggest the solution which emulates T super U. Let me know how to proceed here.

Sorry read your comment in a hurry, you are right. The initial edit was correct here is the link https://tsplay.dev/w28pYm. I'm using experimentalDecorators.

"Let me know how to proceed here" Just post your solution it works.

If you undo that edit then suddenly number is an acceptable type argument because the class is empty and almost anything is assignable to empty class instance types. Did you see what happens if you do that? Unless your class is actually empty in your use case. Is it?

I was undoing it for a different reason but I get your point, it could be misleading. Thanks.

The problem is that you've erroneously written the constraint T extends U, meaning that T must be a subtype of U. But you really want it to be the other way around, where T is a supertype of U. It would be nice if you could write T super U instead, but TypeScript doesn't support such lower bound constraints.  There's a longstanding open feature request for that at microsoft/TypeScript#14520 but so far it's not part of the language.
Luckily you can mostly emulate such a constraint, from the caller's point of view at least. The idea is to use a conditional type that swaps T extends U (which isn't what you want) to U extends T (which is what you want). Like this:
function foo<U>() {
  return function <T extends ([U] extends [T] ? unknown : never)>(
    target: any, propertyKey: any, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<() => T>) {

  };
}

Here's how it works. If U extends T is true, then the check [U] extends [T] succeeds, and the constraint on T becomes T extends unknown which is always true because unknown is the TypeScript top type). But if U extends T is false, then the check [U] extends [T] fails, and the constraint on T becomes T extends never, which is (almost) always false (unless T is never but that's unlikely to happen accidentally) because never is the TypeScript bottom type.
Note that the conditional type is [U] extends [T] ? unknown : never and not U extends T ? unknown : never because the latter would be a distributive conditional type and that's not what you want, since if U is a union type you don't want to check each member of U against T. Wrapping both sides of the check with the one-tuple [+] turns off distributivity while preserving the sense of the check.
And now you get the behavior you expect:
class Baz {
  @foo<Bar>()        // okay
  @foo<null>()       // okay
  @foo<Bar | null>() // okay
  @foo<number>()     // error
  qux(): Bar | null {
    return new Bar();
  }
}

Playground link to code
